# iOS GCM error code 501

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

Recently I start to get this error code whenever I try to use the GCM apis in my iOS app: Error Domain=com.google.gcm Code=501 "(null)"

I couldn't find the meaning of this anywhere? Is that actually the HTTP-status code, meaning Not Implemented?

I'm getting the error first at this line of code:

```
        GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler() { error in  if(error != nil) {   print(error) } }
```

calling the method prints this message :

GCM | GCM registration is not ready with auth credentials

and the error is Error Domain=com.google.gcm Code=501 "(null)"

Comment: Google's doc indicates it as an internal error: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream

Comment: Hmm ok. Wonder why I suddenly start to get this as I have not change any related code. It's been two days now.

Comment: @Siamaster did you try resetting your device and see if it still happens?

Comment: I found the problem, I've answered the question myself. Thanks for help

Comment: @Siamaster I am also facing same problem...have you solved this..please help

Comment: @siamstet i am. not able to figure it out...i am calling thid mehtod in didbecomeactive method.. where i can call this

Comment: I call it at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. I think you sometimes need to refresh your registration token and you will get this error until you refresh the token. Try refreshing your registration token and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurred because I was calling

```
GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler() { error in  if(error != nil) {   print(error) } }
```

before I had received a registration token, or had failed to refresh my token.

"Error Domain=com.google.gcm Code=501 "(null)" " is a really bad error message.

Comment: What should be the ideal solution?

Comment: i found it odd, because even having [[GGLContext sharedInstance] registrationToken] nil sometimes didnt produce any error on connect

Answer (score 0):

if you are been developing using this sample

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExample/

than you have to know, it is quite poor and wrong in some points

to fix the error above (you did request the `[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity` successfully, but still that error pops up), you have to call ALSO 
`[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:` before calling the `[[GCMService sharedInstance] connectWithHandler:`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSError* configureError;
    [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];

    if (configureError) {
        NSLog(@"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);
    }

    GCMConfig *gcmConfig = [GCMConfig defaultConfig];
    gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self;
    [[GCMService sharedInstance] startWithConfig:gcmConfig];

    // add this
    {
        GGLInstanceIDConfig *instanceIDConfig = [GGLInstanceIDConfig defaultConfig];
        instanceIDConfig.delegate = self;

        [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:instanceIDConfig];
    }

    ...
    [self requestAndSynchronizeGCMTokenIfNeeded];
    ...

    return YES;
}
```

BUT remember, you will always get the error, when the `[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:` did not complete, so you should add a chcek for that in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` smth. like

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    if (self.data.deviceToken) {

        [[GCMService sharedInstance] connectWithHandler:^(NSError *error) {

            if (error) {

                NSLog(@"Could not connect to GCM: %@", error.localizedDescription);

            } else {

                self.connectedToGCM = YES;
                NSLog(@"Connected to GCM");

                [self subscribeToTopic];

            }

        }];

    }

}
```

and the last thing, you should try to connect in the handler block of `tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:` as it is sometimes called before the token is recaived and therefore ending in error

```
[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:gcmSenderID scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM options:options handler:^(NSString *token, NSError *error) {
  // connect to GCM also here ([[GCMService sharedInstance] connectWithHandler:)
}
```