# Invalid key in checkin plist: GMSInstanceIDDeviceDataVersion

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

So I followed google's GCM for iOS tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start) but for some reason it wouldn't send notifications to my phone.

I successfully registered with GCM when it asked on my device and when I send the message via their demo, it says it was sent successfully but it unfortunately was never received.

> 2016-04-12 20:58:22.999 GcmExampleSwift[443:]  App measurement v.2003000 started
>   2016-04-12 20:58:23.002 GcmExampleSwift[443:]  To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -GMRDebugEnabled
>   2016-04-12 20:58:23.049: GCM | GCM library version 1.1.4
>   2016-04-12 20:58:23.221: GCM | GCM registration is not ready with auth credentials
>   Could not connect to GCM: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.gcm error 501.)
>   2016-04-12 20:58:23.558 GcmExampleSwift[443:]  App measurement enabled
>   2016-04-12 20:58:23.596: GGLInstanceID | Invalid last checkin timestamp in future.
>   2016-04-12 20:58:23.632: GGLInstanceID | Unable to find token in cache Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-25300 "(null)"
>   2016-04-12 20:58:25.085: GCM | Invalid key in checkin plist: GMSInstanceIDDeviceDataVersion
>   Connected to GCM
>   2016-04-12 20:58:25.431: GGLInstanceID | Unable to find token in cache Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-25300 "(null)"
>   Registration Token: XXXXXXXXXX
>   2016-04-12 20:58:26.578 GcmExampleSwift[443:62016] Subscribed to /topics/global
>   2016-04-12 20:58:38.731 GcmExampleSwift[443:]  Fetched configuration. Status code: 200
>   2016-04-12 20:58:38.731 GcmExampleSwift[443:]  Successful fetched configuration from the server. Got network response. code, size: 200, 124

I noticed there was the issue `Invalid key in checkin plist: GMSInstanceIDDeviceDataVersion`. I'm not really certain this is the ticket, but it's difficult to determine what the issue is exactly when GCM says everything was successful.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918922/proper-sequence-to-get-registration-token-for-gcm-push-notification-on-ios-is-g / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375229/ios-gcm-error-code-501