# GCM for iOS Getting com.google.gcm error 501

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Trying to Integrate GCM to iOS.
Initially the app was working fine and suddenly it is not working.
Getting the following error.

GCM registration is not ready with auth credentials.
Could not connect to GCM: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.gcm error 501.)

Any Help would be greatful.
Thanks.

Comment: same problem here. I´ve downloaded the sample project today, but when i run the error message "GCM registration is not ready with auth credentials" is throwed

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream), The error in the 500-599 range (such as 500 or 503) indicate that there was an internal error in the GCM connection server while trying to process the request, or that the server is temporarily unavailable (for example, because of timeouts). Sender must retry later, honoring any **Retry-After** header included in the response. Application servers must implement exponential back-off.

Also try to refresh your registration [token](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/ios-implementation#refresh_tokens) and see if it works.

Check this SO question [33918922](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918922/proper-sequence-to-get-registration-token-for-gcm-push-notification-on-ios-is-g) and [33375229](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375229/ios-gcm-error-code-501) for more information.